# Filter dataframe with full condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my python function I get a dataframe and a condition as a string.

```
def my_def(df, condition):
```

The goal is to filter the dataframe by the condition, with pandas.

I've seen solutions like this one:

> [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

But it doesn't help me, because the condition parameter looks like this:

```
'name = 'you''
```

The filter is on the column "name" with value "you",

But in the solution above I must split the column name and the value from that string.

Is there a way to filter on all dataframes and not on a specific column?

In the end, It's like doing:

```
"where name = 'you'"
```

on the dataframe, so I guess it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Would `df.query("name == 'you'")` solve your problem? Or is it an issue that you have only one `=` (equal sign)?

Comment: Thanks for your help! the query function great. with "==" but that's ok.
Is there a way to do same whit condition of null ? (is null or is not null).
Because the check of nulls in column in pandas is different from the simple condition "name is null"..